# The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator. document type: users

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, rights

For some reason, I get the following error when a mentor tries to edit their own recruitment projects:

The requested operation cannot be performed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: users, action: read) - (Records: [11 ,45, 109, 122, 155], User: 21)

I checked and all the permission settings work and there are individual bugs, not everyone has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the model in the error message has an access rule that doesn't allow the user to read certain records, in your case the model should be res_users or res_partner.

I am not sure about the exact path in Odoo 11 but in Odoo 12 you should activate the developer mode and navigate to Settings -> Technical -> Security -> Record Rules and search Object by typing the model name.

Check the rules that appear, by deactivating one by one you can find out which one is causing the issue and decide if you want to deactivate it or change the rule definition.